# Can I check if SQL REPLACE finds match in single query then update second field?

Tags: sql, replace

As title suggests if I were to run a replace query and it's successful, I then want to update a field in that same query if possible.

```
UPDATE users 
   SET solved = REPLACE(solved, ',testsolved123', '') AS match if match = true, SET found = found +1;
```

I realise this statement wouldn't work, I'm just trying to convey the logic I'm after, is there a case method?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you want to use a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE users
    SET solved = REPLACE(solved, ',testsolved123', ''),
        found = found + 1
    WHERE solved like '%,testsolved123%';
```

I have no idea what the `concat()` is supposed to be doing.

It also seems like you are storing comma-delimited lists in a single string columns.  That is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: The delimited list here is only an example, I'm using hyphens, is this still not a good idea? ignore the concat, was a mistake, I've updated post.